# How to show PHP value on Developer Console when communication as Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, http, post, get

I use WordPress to build a site.

WordPress has a lot of plugins, most of which use Ajax technology to communicate with the server.
I'm using a big plug-in (WPML), and I want to know how it works,
I wanted to print the value of php variable using echo and print_f in the 
WPML's PHP source code.

However, the amount of source code for the plugin is so great that it is very difficult to find the JS code that receives the response from the server. If I can find the JS code, of course I can put `console.log(response)` or `console.log(data)` in the callback function.

**But if I can not do that(in my case, I couldn't find the JS code), can not I see the result of `echo $some_value`** ?

**How can I see when the browser and the server are exchanging data(by POST or GET method)?**

Comment: Obviously, echoing something needs to be added in the PHP code. And yes, if you do not add it there, you can not inspect any PHP variable. So what exactly is your question? Are you looking for basics of debugging, for example using Xdebug or the Zend debugger?

Comment: @NicoHaase My question is this - How can I see `echo $some_value`'s result on Developer Console when ajax communication if I can not find `jQuery.post(url, data, function( response ){ if (response.result == 201) ~~  })` this JS code!

Comment: you can also use [ChromePhp](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp) to log server side variables into the console.  Works on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It's irrelevant where the AJAX call is coming from - add something to your response in PHP and it will be outputted in the console. Or have a look at XDebug or the Zend debugger to perform proper debugging

Comment: @billynoah Thank you ;D

Comment: @NicoHaase OK. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome you can see this here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can see `echo $some_value` result on Developer Console's **Networking** part(xhr) !